# Как передать список из одного метода класса Django в другой?

Tags: python, django, ajax, ооп

Я делаю интернет-магазин на Django. В классе `ProductsCatalogListView`, который отображает и фильтрует данные, есть два метода:

- `get_context_data` - создает контекст и также фильтрует товары по категориям;
- `post` - срабатывает при ajax-запросе из JS, фильтрует товары по определенным критериям.

Но для того, чтобы фильтровать их в методе `post`, должен быть список
товаров выбранной категории. Я никак не могу передать список из `get_context_data` в `post`. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Вот тот класс:

```py
class ProductsCatalogListView(ListView):
    model = Products
    context_object_name = 'products'
    template_name = "products/products_catalog.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductsCatalogListView, self).get_context_data(object_list=None, **kwargs)
        context['products'] = Products.objects.all()
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.annotate(c=Count('products')).filter(c__gt=0)

        print(self.kwargs)
        if 'category' in self.kwargs:
            if 'all_products' in self.kwargs:
                context['products'] = Products.objects.all()
            else:
                context['products'] = Products.objects.filter(category__slug=self.kwargs['category'])
        else:
            context['products'] = Products.objects.all()

        products_list = context['products']
        print('-----------------------', products_list)
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Получите данные о выбранных чекбоксах из запроса
        selected_checkboxes = request.POST.getlist('selected_checkboxes[]')

        if 'composition_checkbox_edible' in selected_checkboxes:
            filtered_products = self.products.filter(is_edible=True)
        elif 'composition_checkbox_inedible' in selected_checkboxes:
            filtered_products = self.products.filter(is_edible=False)
        else:
            filtered_products = self.products
        data = [{
            'id': product.id,
            'title': product.title,
            'is_edible': product.is_edible,
            'price': product.price,
            'images': [image.image.url for image in Gallery.objects.filter(product=product)]} for product in filtered_products]
        print(data)

        return JsonResponse({'products': data})
```